# Javascript merge two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to merge two arrays in Javascript like this:

```
['First', 'Third', 'Fifth', 'Seventh', 'Ninth']
['Second', 'Fourth', 'Sixth', 'Eigth']
=> ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth',...]
```

Also One array can have more elements than another one. So for example:

```
['E1', 'E2', 'E3']
['E4']
=> ['E1', 'E4', 'E2', 'E3']
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

I don't really have in idea how to do this.

note: I have underscorejs available.

Comment: Obligatory - [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Boaz I don't really know what should I try. I would probably spend a lot of time to solve this. While somebody here could solve it in few minutes or already once did.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site not a requests forum. As such, you are expected to post *questions* about specific problems in your code and not a list of requirements for code you haven't written.

Comment: @Boaz Thanks, I'll try account this in future.

Comment: @user1188570: Spending time solving problems is what makes you a better programmer. You'll likely learn a bunch of other stuff while you research and experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With underscore:

```
var a1 = ['First', 'Third', 'Fifth', 'Seventh', 'Ninth'];
var a2 = ['Second', 'Fourth', 'Sixth', 'Eigth'];

var result = _.compact(_.flatten(_.zip(a1, a2)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['First', 'Third', 'Fifth', 'Seventh', 'Ninth'];
b = ['Second', 'Fourth', 'Sixth', 'Eigth'];
c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (i < a.length) c.push(a[i]);
  if (i < b.length) c.push(b[i]);
}
```